# How to remove git stashes when inside magit-status

Tags: magit, git

Inside the magit-status, I see tons of stashes.

Can I removed them by pressing a key on the keyboard?

Comment: Do you want to hide them from the display or delete the stashes completely?

Comment: i want to remove completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to the relevant stash, and <kbd>k</kbd> to kill.

If you move to the `Stashes` heading and type <kbd>k</kbd> on that line you can remove them all.